# Click filefield button?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, extjs

I have a file field button that once click will allow you to upload a file. Here's what i got so far, but it's not firing the upload dialog:

```
var button = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('filefield[name=yourbuttonname]')[0];
button.fireEvent('click', button);
```

Comment: Does it work when you click with the mouse? Do you want to programmatically 'click' instead of a real click? Your question is not clear, because it seems to be about a real click, while your code is about a virtual click.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `<input>` and `type="file"`
and get the change event from this element.

```js
$('#fileup').change(function() {
  $('.file').html($(this).val());
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fileup" type="file" />
<span class="file" style="border:5px solid red;"></span>
```

Comment: This question is for ExtJs, not jquery.